# How to display a very accurate number?

Tags: python, format

I want to output two numbers that differ very slightly from each other.

```
1.0000000000
1.0000000001
```

I don't want a long line. Rounding or scientific notation doesn't help me.

```
>>> round(1.0000000000, 6)
1.0
>>> round(1.0000000001, 6)
1.0
>>> f"{1.0000000001:e}"
'1.000000e+00'
>>> f"{1.0000000000:e}"
'1.000000e+00'
```

I like the solution in matplotlib. There, the number is presented as the sum of the major part and fractional. So the numbers presented above will look like this:

```
1 + 0 * 1e-10,
1 + 1 * 1e-10
```

[image]

I can implement this myself, but suddenly you know any libraries or standard tools for this.
Do you know the existing tools for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got an answer.

So far I tried to implement the functionality of matplotib.

True, the code is crude, but I'll save it here, suddenly it will be useful to someone.
Pass the list of objects to Decimal!!!

```
def prepare_display(numbers, accuracy):
    from decimal import Decimal
    ACCURACY = 3
    numbers_sorted = sorted(numbers)
    diffs = []
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        diffs.append(numbers_sorted[i] - numbers_sorted[i - 1])
    if min(diffs) > 1 * 10 ** (-ACCURACY):
        return '', numbers
    total_part = min(numbers)

    differents = []
    exps = []
    for number in numbers:
        diff = number - total_part
        differents.append(diff)
        exps.append(fexp(diff))
    min_exp = min(exps)

    different_parts = []
    for diff in differents:
        different_parts.append(round(diff / Decimal(10 ** min_exp)))
    total_part = Decimal(total_part)
    return str(round(total_part, - min_exp - 1)) + ' + x * 1e' \ 
           str(min_exp),
           different_parts

def fexp(number):
    """Returns the exponent of a decimal number"""
    from decimal import Decimal
    (sign, digits, exponent) = Decimal(number).as_tuple()
    return len(digits) + exponent - 1
```

Then for the following cases there will be a corresponding result.

For numbers less than one

```
>>>> numbers = [Decimal('0.999990'), Decimal('0.999992')]
>>>> total_part, different_parts = prepare_display(numbers)
>>>> print(total_part)
>>>> print(different_parts)
0.99999 + x * 1e-6
[0, 2]
```

If no conversion is needed

```
>>>> numbers = [1, 2]
>>>> total_part, different_parts = prepare_display(numbers, 3)
>>>> print(total_part)
>>>> print(different_parts)

[1, 2]
```

The code is very crude

Answer (score 0):

Maybe library decimal is useful. For example:

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = Decimal(1.0000000000)
>>> b = Decimal(1.0000000001)
>>> 
>>> a
Decimal('1')
>>> b
Decimal('1.0000000001000000082740370999090373516082763671875')
>>>
>>> a == b
False
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a short line.